# How to switch agents from one breed to another during a simulation?

Tags: netlogo

I have a stock market simulation with two types of breeds, passive and active. They both have different formulas for investing. However, I would like the agents to switch between the two breed types. I have a condition they should follow to decide when to switch. However, I am not sure how to program the agents to switch.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply `set` the `breed` of an agent, just as would any other variable:

```
ask one-of passives [ set breed actives ]
```

Assuming you used `passives` and `actives` as your breed plural names.

You can read more in [the NetLogo programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#breeds).

Comment: something like this:to switch
  ask passives
  [r > rhat) [set breed adults]]
end

Comment: you need to use `with` to filter, so `ask passives with [r > rhat] [ set breed adults ]]`

Comment: This is what I did:           to switch-A
  ask managers-A
  with [Rhat-A < mean-Rhat-P] [set breed managers-P]
end

Comment: how can I tell if the breeds are changing?

Comment: If you mean, tell in your model, just add a `show` statement or change the agents display somehow in your `switch-A`.  Like so `to switch-A ask managers-A with [Rhat-A < mean-Rhat-P] [ set breed managers-P set color blue show "Switched!" ] end`